# Use UTF-8 characters inside mail body

Tags: r, email, utf-8

I am using windows 7 and R 3.5.1.

If somebody is familiiar with balstula package (https://github.com/rich-iannone/blastula), I would like to know is it possible to use UTF-8 characters in email body.
I tried this:

```
email <- compose_email(
  body = "
  Hello Mislav Šagovac",
  encoding = "UTF-8")

send_email_out(
  message = email,
  from = "mislav.sagovac@contentio.biz",
  to = "mislav.sagovac@contentio.biz",
  subject = "Testni mail",
  creds_file = ".e_creds"
  )
```

and this

```
test <- "Hello Mislav Šagovac"
Encoding(test) <- "UTF-8"
send_email_out(
  message = email,
  from = "mislav.sagovac@contentio.biz",
  to = "mislav.sagovac@contentio.biz",
  subject = "Testni mail",
  creds_file = ".e_creds"
  )
```

but it didn't worked.

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, but body of sent e-mail doesn't show utf-8 characters. Above package allow to include markdown inside email body, but if I include Croatian characters inside mardown text it want show it in e-mail.